# How to use async await methods when data is required for comparison

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, asynchronous, thread-safety

I'm learning about `async` calls and started using them in my Xamarin project. Very often, my app is running into deadlocks for using `.Result` at the end of my `async` methods. I'm using `SQLiteAsyncConnection` for local database on device, which only provides `async` operations on tables and we're consuming data from web services using `HttpClient` which is also async compatible only.

How can I run an `async` method and compare the data that I receive without using `.Result` at the end of the `async` method?

I've looked into deadlocks and came to an understanding that using `.Result` on `async` methods is a very bad idea. So, how do I use these `async` methods and still get the data instantly without using `.Result()` and not get into any dead locks.

```
var dbStudent = App.LocalDB.GetStudentFromLocalDBonDevice(studentId).Result;

if(dbStudent.IsEnrolled == false){
//do something here
}
```

If I don't use `.Result()` at the end, I'm unable to access the `dbStudent.IsEnrolled` in the code and the error message at compile time says

> Task does not contain definition for IsEnrolled and no
>   accessible extension method IsEnrolled accepting a first argument of
>   type Task could be found

Do I have any options here other than creating synchronous methods?

Comment: Can't you use `await App.LocalDB.GetStudentFromLocalDBonDevice(studentId)` instead?

Comment: Thanks. That works! But I had to change the method where I'm calling this to async as well. So, using await on async method and instantly accessing the properties on data won't cause any deadlocks? @MuhammadHannan

Comment: Yes, in your case.

Comment: I'm also using db update function to update rows in a for loop. Having await function won't cause any dead locks even if we loop through?

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: Is it a good practice to call an async update method in a loop?
Does this create any deadlocks as it is updating to the same table (same resource) ?
`foreach(var student in listOfStudents)
{
student.IsEnrolled = true;
await App.LocalDB.UpdateStudentAsync(student);
}`

Comment: If your `UpdateStudentAsync` function is doing async operations and you're awating each one of them it won't cause any trouble.

Comment: Thank you!! @MuhammadHannan